# VLC Plays Local Files, Does not Play Files on SMB Share

Tags: networking, sound, samba, vlc, media

VLC Media player is not playing files on my SMB Network Share, although it plays local media fine. I get this error when I try to play from the share:

Your input can't be opened:
VLC is unable to open the MRL 'smb://pi@192.168.1.2/Files/Caden/Music/FINALE.mp3'. Check the log for details.

But, when I download the file, it plays it fine. Help?

EDIT: This is VLC's output when opened in the terminal:

```
VLC media player 2.2.2 Weatherwax (revision 2.2.2-0-g6259d80)
[0000000001c21148] core libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
KSambaShare: Could not find smb.conf!
libdvdnav: Using dvdnav version 5.0.3
libdvdread: Couldn't find device name.
libdvdread:DVDOpenFilePath:findDVDFile /VIDEO_TS/VIDEO_TS.IFO failed
libdvdread:DVDOpenFilePath:findDVDFile /VIDEO_TS/VIDEO_TS.BUP failed
libdvdread: Can't open file VIDEO_TS.IFO.
libdvdnav: vm: failed to read VIDEO_TS.IFO
[0000000001cefd68] core playlist: stopping playba
```

Comment: Seems to be a file path issue, just mount your filesystem without using ubuntu's native gui. see https://gist.github.com/ipbastola/eaa107b4640262a108fcc3ef57d24836

Answer (score 3):

That's a known VLC issue.  It never did.  When you mount your network share, its files are also shown in the `/run/user/your_user_id/gvfs` folder.  Locate the file you want to play in that folder and play it from there.

Comment: 1. I cannot find the files there. 2. VLC for Windows plays the files just fine.

Answer (score 1):

i set in smb.conf

> min protocol = SMB1
>
> max protocol = SMB1

and works fine

Comment: Worked at first on my Feren OS (Ubuntu 20 based) then stopped working... so weird

Comment: probably a bad idea, see https://www.google.com/search?channel=fs&client=ubuntu&q=smb1+security+issues

Answer (score 0):

I had issues with VLC not playing from my NAS. It gave 'Bad file descriptor' error. The solution was to switch off some advanced SMB parameters on the NAS file sharing setting.

By the way, regardless of the settings, the Windows Media Player could play those videos.

Answer (score 0):

I had issues with VLC installed via snap on Ubuntu 20, I switch to regular apt install and now it works as expected :

```bsh
sudo snap remove vlc
sudo apt install vlc
```

Comment: This made no difference to me on u22.04